# Are there any parts where 'react-native-mmkv' and 'redux' should be viewed differently? for react-native

Tags: react-native

I use both 'react-native-mmkv' and 'redux' in my project, but there is no big difference in the way data is stored and used.
Aside from the performance, what's better for storing and using data securely? Or is it better to use both methods?

I am sorry that I am not good at English.

is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    Text,
    Pressable,
} from 'react-native';

// UI components
import { Button } from 'atoms';
import { Card, SelectList } from 'molecules';

// Hooks
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

// Redux
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from 'hooks';

// utils
import { initializeAccountData } from 'utils';
import { useMMKVString } from "react-native-mmkv";

const App = ({ navigation, route }: any) =\> {
    // Navigation
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    // Redux
    // const { accounts } = useAppSelector(state =\> state.accounts);
    // const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    // MMKV Hooks
    const \[accounts, setAccount\] = useMMKVString('accounts')

    // Update to didMount, update
    React.useEffect(() =\> {
        const dataInitialize = async () =\> {
            await initializeAccountData();
        }
        dataInitialize();
    }, \[\]);
    
    // Update to page focusing
    React.useEffect(() =\> {

    }, \[isFocused\]);

    // Update to account change
    React.useEffect(() =\> {

    }, \[accounts\]);

    return (
        \<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}\>
            ...
        \</SafeAreaView\>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is in memory storage, if you kill your app you will lose app state.

MMKV is persistent storage and you need to use it if you want to save data for the long term.

You can connect MMKV with redux if you want to store redux state. An example is here https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/blob/master/docs/WRAPPER_REDUX.md

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

curiosity that arose because the MMKV was not persistently.
It was probably a issue caused by using hook as a new constructor instead of using it!